# Replacing last colon occurrence

Tags: python, string

I have

```
01:22:33:22
```

I would like to replace the last colon in a timecode with a semi-colon, resulting in `01:22:33;22`.

Originally I was using

```
colon = tcode.rfind(":")
new_tcode = tcode[:colon] + ";" + tcode[colon+1:]
```

I'm now getting errors such as "object has no attribute 'rfind'".

Comment: The "ex" in "regex" already means "expression".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`rsplit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) and `maxsplit=1`:

```
d = "01:22:33:22"
print(';'.join(i for i in d.rsplit(':',1)) )
```

Comment: Why `i for i in d.rsplit(':',1)`? Why not just `';'.join(d.rsplit(':',1))`?

Answer (score 0):

This regex works:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(":(?=[^:]*$)", ";", "01:22:33:22")
'01:22:33;22'
```

Comment: Using a regex is dubious and probably slower than `rsplit`, though.